# "Invalid SockJS path - required to have 3 path segments"-error with websockets

Tags: python, spring-boot, websocket

I am trying to subscribe (from a Python client) to an endpoint (spring boot server) using websockets. The Python client gets the response/error: 
"*Handshake status 404 None* 
### closed ###"

The spring boot server generates the error message "*Invalid SockJS path '/topic/people-counter' - required to have 3 path segments*". Anyone have any idea what the issue could be? It feels like I've tried a lot of combinations of urls, but with no success. FYI, I also have an Angular-application that is able to connect to this endpoint, but I do not think it is relevant to show the code here.

**Python code:**

```
import rel
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")


def main() -> None:
    url = "ws://localhost:8080/stomp-endpoint/topic/people-counter"

    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url,
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)  # Set dispatcher to automatic reconnection
    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
    rel.dispatch()
```

**Spring boot:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint")
        .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
        .withSockJS();
  }
}
```